# Accept any enum as parameter

Tags: java

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> enumHeadAsList(final Class<E> val, final E topValue)
{
    // My code
}
```

I want to make a method that accept any enum i give and i set a default value of that enum to do some order check and then return all values as list. Basically i want set head of an enum and return values. So far i managed to do this but i don't know how to continue.

I want call the following method like:

`enumHeadAsList(BuffType.class, BuffType.SELF);`

Comment: please can you re-elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: I basically want to give an enum values and a default value of this enum and sort it and bring the default value on top and return it as List with the enum values.

Comment: Yes i managed to figure out but i want do a loop inside to check and swap to bring defautlValue on top. Class won't help me do the loot so BuffType.values() maybe is better? But how i declare that in parameter?

Comment: so you want a list that contains in first position the "default" enum you have passed, and then all the others?

Comment: Yes sir. And return these as list (i know how to do that). Basically re-order any enum value base on the given. I want the default to be on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> enumHeadAsList(final E topValue)
{
  E[] values = topValue.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
  if (topValue.ordinal() != 0) {
    E oldTop = values[0];
    values[0] = topValue;
    values[topValue.ordinal()] = oldTop;
  }
  return List.of(values);
}
```

This code assumes that you don't care too much about the order of the remaining elements (as the top element is simply swapped with the previously first one).

If you want to keep the relative order of the other values intact, then you'll have to tweak replace the `if` above with this code block:

```
final int topValueIndex = topValue.ordinal();
if (topValueIndex != 0) {
  System.arraycopy(values, 0, values, 1, topValueIndex);
  values[0] = topValue;
}
```

Note that a dedicated `Class<E>` parameter is not needed if `topValue` is not allowed to be `null`, because we can get the enum class from `topValue`.

If using a Java version before Java 9, then you can replace `List.of()` with `Arrays.asList()` with the difference that the resulting `List` would be mutable.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!. I'll change it a bit into java 16 style but it works pretty good. Didn't know i could make it without even declare as parameter the enum type. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tremors94: I'm curious what you mean by Java 16 style. Streams? `var`?

Answer (score 1):

[EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) makes this easy:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> enumHeadAsList(final Class<E> val, final E topValue)
{
    List<E> values = new ArrayList<>();

    values.add(topValue);
    values.addAll(EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(topValue)));

    return values;
}
```

`complementOf` returns a collection of all enum values except those present in the argument.  So, complementOf(EnumSet.of(topValue)) is all values except topValue.